# Multiline regression equation in Latex

Tags: equations

Noob here. I'm trying to put together a multiline multivariate regression equation in Latex and am having some issues.

```
$ {Unit.Sales_t} = \alpha + \beta_{1} Date_{t} + \beta_{2}  Cable.TV_{t} + \beta_{3}  Int.Display_{t} + \beta_{4}  Local.Radio_{t} + \beta_{5}  Magazines_{t} + \beta_{6}  Network.TV_{t} + \beta_{7}  Spot.TV_{t} + \epsilon$
```

I'm trying to match the regression parameters so that it's not one long set of new lines. It should be something along the following lines.

```
Unit.Sales = A + B1 Date +
                 B2 Cable.TV +
                 B3 Int.Display +
....
```

Or some variation of the above type so that each predictor is on a separate line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  You can either use `aligned` if you want to start in the paragraph, but better to make it display mode and use `align*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the equations to be in display mode (i.e, set on their own line you can achieve your desired results with the `align*` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` and provides some fixes.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Unit.Sales}_{t} = \alpha 
    &+ \beta_{1}  \mathrm{Date}_{t} \\
    &+ \beta_{2}  \mathrm{Cable.TV}_{t}    \\
    &+ \beta_{3}  \mathrm{Int.Display}_{t} \\
    &+ \beta_{4}  \mathrm{Local.Radio}_{t} \\
    &+ \beta_{5}  \mathrm{Magazines}_{t}   \\
    &+ \beta_{6}  \mathrm{Network.TV}_{t}  \\
    &+ \beta_{7}  \mathrm{Spot.TV}_{t} + \epsilon
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\epsilon` term should have a subscript `t` as well, right?

Comment: @Mico: Don't know so will defer that to the OP (it isn't in the MWE provided in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Or the `aligned` one:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\[
    \begin{aligned}
    \mathrm{Unit.Sales}_{t} = \alpha 
        &+ \beta_{1}  \mathrm{Date}_{t} \\
        &+ \beta_{2}  \mathrm{Cable.TV}_{t}    \\
        &+ \beta_{3}  \mathrm{Int.Display}_{t} \\
        &+ \beta_{4}  \mathrm{Local.Radio}_{t} \\
        &+ \beta_{5}  \mathrm{Magazines}_{t}   \\
        &+ \beta_{6}  \mathrm{Network.TV}_{t}  \\
        &+ \beta_{7}  \mathrm{Spot.TV}_{t} + \epsilon
    \end{aligned}
\]
    \end{document}
```

Sometimes it works better.

Comment: It should be `\mathrm{Unit.Sales}_{t}`. This is not the same as Peter's, because one can give a global equation number. Also `split` could be used, perhaps even better.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit.